# Use of undefined constant Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

Controller Code:

```php
$tokenAmount = json_decode($token->getBody())->result;
return view('account')->with(compact('tokenAmount'));
```

View Code:

```php
<label>Wallet Balance {{tokenAmount}}</label>
```

When I run the code. I'm getting following error.

> Use of undefined constant tokenAmount - assumed 'tokenAmount'

PS: I tried following method also.

```php
$tokenAmount = json_decode($token->getBody())->result;
return view('account', compact('tokenAmount'));
```

If I do `echo $tokenAmount`, it is printing the value without any error.

Comment: You forgot `$` in your view: `<label>Wallet Balance {{ $tokenAmount }}</label>`. If you accessing a variable in blade view you need also use `$`.

Comment: Yeah. I forgot. Thank you very much for reminding that.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your view code and check like:

```
<label>Wallet Balance {{tokenAmount}}</label>
```

to

```
<label>Wallet Balance {{$tokenAmount}}</label>
```